# Using & operation boolean

Tags: c++

I can't figure out this statement in a program...what does this statement mean in following code? How is the operation performed?

```
ok = ok & a[c[i][j]] [c[i][k]];


    bool ok = 1;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < c[i].size(); j++)
            for(unsigned int k = j + 1; k < c[i].size(); k++)
                ok = ok & a[c[i][j]] [c[i][k]];
                //print yes if ok = 1
```

Comment: `&` is a [bitwise AND operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic). The rest is array access.

Comment: a[c[i][j]] [c[i][k]] is a single entity, like it has some specific value OR it has a set of values?

Comment: Yes, `a` is probably a two-dimensional array. You could also do `a[0][0]`

Comment: `rowIndex = c[i][j]; colIndex = c[i][k]; ok = ok & a[rowIndex][colIndex];`

Comment: Thanks that cleared it.

Comment: @guest77312 without knowing the type of `a` one can only guess, but if `a` is two-dimensional array of `int`s, than `ok = ok & a[row][col];` accumulates the least significant bits of `a` elements into `ok`

Comment: a is vector of vectors of boolean type, vector<vector<bool> > a;